# npm start - using CORS

Tags: node.js, npm, angular

I'm working on a little app, using Angular2. In the [5min. Quickstart Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) npm is used to install required modules and to start a lite-server. Later I want to use that app within a normal web-server and build mobile apps with cordova. How ever, I'm using a REST api to load some data. How can I configure the lite-server to solve CORS pre-flight OPTIONS check? My apache server (on a dedicated server) is already configured, but I don't want to commit, update and recompile every little change. I need a corresponding configuration to this:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://my-domain.net:12345"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
```

Comment: For what I understand in your architecture your lite-server only serves your client/browser app, its static content like js scripts, css and html, those files will request data to your tomcat server though http calls, those calls are the ones that can give the CORS error if the tomcat server is not adding those headers into the response, so you don't really need to configure the lite-server, you are not doing requests from the tomcat server to the static content server are you?

Comment: hmm, I'm doing REST calls from the lite-server to my main server (which is in a different domain that the local web-server). And I always got an CORS error. Check Thierrys answer; it works now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built-in option to do that within the lite-server. That said, you can patch it but I don't really see what you try to do here...

After having installed it, you can go into the `node_modules/lite-server` folder and install the [`connect-cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-cors) module:

```
npm install connect-cors
```

Then in the `lib/lite-server.js file`, you can import the module and use it the middleware array after:

```
var historyFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
var log = require('connect-logger');
var cors = require('connect-cors'); //  <------------------
(...)

sync.init({
  port: argv.port || 3000,
  server: {
    baseDir: options.baseDir,
    middleware: [
      cors(), //  <------------------
      log(),
      historyFallback({ index: options.fallback })
    ]
  },
  files: options.files,
});
```

When starting the server with the following command the CORS support is usable:

```
./bin/lite-server --baseDir ../../
```

By adding an `Origin` header in requests, you will see CORS headers in the response.

Comment: That does it. And what I'm doing is just developing on my local maschine instead of my server (as said, I didn't want to commit every change, and unless the headers are correct it won't work), thanks.

Comment: consider the last answer, seems to work for me: http-server -o --cors

Answer (score 5):

I found with http-server

`http-server -o --cors`

Answer (score 1):

actually the lite-server is just a wrapper of browser-sync, if you can check the documents from https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options, you can find the configuration of cors, and because lite-server support use a config file to set the options, so all you need to do is just set a config file for lite-server, you can select bs-config.js or bs-config.json, if we use the easiest one bs-config.json, the contente is:

```
{
    "cors": true
}
```

then you directly start lite-server, you can see:

**browser-sync config**

```
{ injectChanges: false,
  files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
  watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
  server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] },
  cors: true }
```

**[BS] Access URLs:**

```
   Local: http://localhost:3000
```

that means cors works.

Comment: this doesn't work, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is still not sent

Comment: don't work your solution, did u test it?

Answer (score 0):

I dont sure that it solution work, but how variant u need install "connect-cors" to project, then in bs-config.js will write for example next:

```
var cors = require('connect-cors');

module.exports = {
  port: 3000,
  files: [
    './src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}'
  ],
  server: {
    baseDir: './build/',
    middleware: {
      // default middlewares for lite-server https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/blob/HEAD/lib/config-defaults.js
      3: cors({ origins: ['https://example-site.com'] }),
    },
  },
};
```